# How to save the ensemble machine learning model in .h5 and json?

Tags: python, keras

I have the problem when saving the Ensemble model. In my case, I have made the LSTM model by keras library, then using BaggingRegressor from scikit learn to make robust model. Then need to save the ensemble bagging but find no way to save under .h5 and json file as tutorial on https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/

My code is as below

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor

def model_base_LSTM(inputshape): # inputshape normally x_train.shape[2] or x_train.shape[1]

    model_ = Sequential([

    # Make layers
    LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(1,inputshape)),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dropout(0.15),
    LSTM(100, return_sequences=True),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dropout(0.15),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Flatten(),
    # Output layer
    Dense(1)
    ])
    # Compile
    model_.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

    return model_

model = MyKerasRegressor(build_fn = model_base_LSTM, epochs=20, batch_size =50, validation_split=0.3, 
                         inputshape = x_train.shape[1])

bag_mod = BaggingRegressor(base_estimator=model, n_estimators=5)
bag_mod_train = bag_mod.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())
```

After training the model, I would like to save the 'bag_mod' model but the way scikit learn save model is not like keras (as in the link refered). Desired to save in both .h5 and .json file. So, How to save this trained model for the next time training with update data?

Thanks a lot!